# How to know which observable triggers change in Rx.Observable.combineLatest

Tags: rxjs, observable

I can use Rx.Observable.combineLatest so that I will notify  the changes whenever any observable changes. But how can I know which observable changes?

```
var s1 = someObservable1();
var s2 = someObservable2();
Rx.Observable.combineLatest(s1, s2).subscribe(function(){
    // How to know which Observable triggers combineLatest change

});
```

Answer (score 11):

RxJs provides no means to accomplish this. Nevertheless you can do it with additional state:

```js
var trigger = "";

Rx.Observable
  .combineLatest(
    s1.do(function() { trigger = "s1"; }),
    s2.do(function() { trigger = "s2"; }))
  .subscribe(function(){
    // use trigger
  });
```

Comment: looks so dirty, since we store state outside of the pipeline. Doesn't look good. But definitely works

Comment: making a tuple (item, timestamp) and combining them together than taking the item which has greater timestamp as last event works as well.

Having external variable doesn't seem like right approach

Comment: I agree with @denis631. In fact, it seems that many RX implementation have a `Timestamp()` operator built in. 

https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timestamp.html#:~:text=RxJS%20timestamp,emitted%20by%20the%20source%20Observable.